# How can I avoid logging file not founds commonly caused by vulnerability scanners?

Tags: security, logging, apache-2.4

My apache logs are pretty much full of `'admin.php' not found or unable to stat` and similar statements for `wp-login.php`, `default.php`, and so on that are often sought after by vulnerability scanners. Can I configure apache to avoid logging these statements for certain files? I don't want to filter out all file not founds as I'd like to fix bad links that I may have put out over the years that no longer correspond to the same files.

I can use a tool like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), but from previous experiences it comes from so many places that those errors are still going to pile up, and the reducing those error messages are what this question is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Apache's [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive allows for evaluating environment variables in order to decide whether to log a message. And environment variables can be set depending on the URI using [SetEnvIf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif). So to exclude all requests for URIs ending with wp-login.php from the combined custom log:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "wp-login.php$" dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```

Note that you need [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) for SetEnvIf to work.

Comment: Make sure you remember to remove it if you do one day install wordpress though!

Comment: Trying to get your answer to work. I've put the SetEnvIf into my main apache2.conf (and I do have mod_setenvif enabled), and then I went to one of my individual site confs and added the the env=!dontlog to the end of my CustomLog location. Is the environmental variable being held onto between the time that these get read? We can take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15034/apache2-configuration) if anyone wants to help.